VS Code, persistent "Your Code installation appears to be corrupt. Please reinstall."
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS

So I did these commands
sudo apt remove code
cd Downloads/
sudo apt install ./code_1.94.2-1728494015_amd64.deb  # Latest as of today

But when I boot up VS Code, either which code command from from GUI, I still get

Your Code installation appears to be corrupt. Please reinstall.

Can anyone help identify what is corrupt?
